# Angular JS http Request to .NET Server

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, ajax, curl

Im trying to make a `post` request to a .NET server using Angular JS

I am able to get a response but the server is not seeing my request data.

Client:

```
var header = {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"};

var data = {name:"bill", email:"bill@email.com", phone:"1234567890" };

$http.post("//dot.net/resource", data, header).then(function(res){

    console.log(res.data);

},function(err){ console.log(err); });
```

Server:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToString().ToLower() == "post") {

    Response.Write("hello request");      // I see this in the response
    Response.Write(Request.Form["name"]); // nothing : (
}
```

Im not super familiar with `.NET`. Is `Request.Form` the basically like `$_POST` in php?

How can I pass some variable over to the server using `$http`?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the data as string by using `JSON.stringify(data)`. And additionally you can explicitly specify content type header
`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`